# Different result in forloop?

Tags: perl

I want to print like this

```
    xxx
   xxxxx
  xxxxxxx
 xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

I achive this by following code

```
$s = "x";
$z = 5;
$m = 1;

$m = $m+2,
$z--,
$c = " " x $z,
$st = $s x $m,
print "$c$st\n",
for(1..5);
```

My doubt

when i used increment and decrement operator after the print function it gave the different result
Script is

```
$c = " " x $z,
$st = $s x $m,
print "$c$st\n",
$m = $m+2,
$z--,
for(1..5);
```

It result is

```
     x
35    xxx
54   xxxxx
73  xxxxxxx
92 xxxxxxxxx
```

Here 3 5 7 9 are printed by the `$m` and `5 4 3 2` are printed by the `$z`. 
But, i not directly print the `$m` and `$z` then why it gave `$m` and `$z` value? How it is work?

Comment: ALLWAYS `use strict; use warnings;` at the begining of your scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
$c = " " x $z,
$st = $s x $m,
print "$c$st\n",
$m = $m+2,
$z--,
for(1..5);
```

is parsed as:

```
$c = " " x $z,
$st = $s x $m,
print ("$c$st\n", $m = $m+2, $z--),
for(1..5);
```

You can force different parsing by using parentheses:

```
$c = " " x $z,
$st = $s x $m,
print ("$c$st\n"),
$m = $m+2,
$z--
for(1..5);
```

But I rather suggest the following:

```
for(1..5) {
  $c = " " x $z;
  $st = $s x $m;
  print ("$c$st\n");
  $m = $m+2;
  $z--;
}
```

That way you are not relying on any operator precedence which might bite you. You will immediately see which statements are contained in the loop too. (I had to read your initial code thrice to finally get it)